# ThreeJS - pan camera vertically without tilting?

Tags: three.js, camera, pan

I am using Mr Doob's periodic table code in my web app:

https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

I am using it in *Helix* view.  When I rotate the object left, I shift the camera's Y position by a certain amount too.  My desire is to give the impression that the Helix is *corkscrewing* vertically up and down as you rotate the camera.  This is the code I'm using, where *angle* and *panAmount* are constants that control how much rotation and vertical pan takes place per second:

```
    let g_RotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

    g_RotationMatrix.makeRotationY(angle);

    // Apply matrix like this to rotate the camera.
    self.object.position.applyMatrix4(g_RotationMatrix);

    // Shift it vertically too.         
    self.object.position.y += panAmount;

    // Make camera look at the target.
    self.object.lookAt(self.target);
```

The problem I'm having is that from the camera's perspective, the object appears to tilt towards you and away from you respectively, depending on the rotation direction, as the camera shifts vertically.  This makes sense to me because the I'm guessing that the *lookat()* function causes the camera to look at the center of the target, and not at point on the target that is closest point to it, so the camera has to tilt to focus on the targe's center of mass.  I see the same effect when I use the mouse to pan vertically using the Orbit controls.  I believe another way to describe the effect is that the object appears to *pitch* up and down as the camera shifts vertically.

The effect I want instead is that of a window washer on an automated lift being raised up and down the side of building, with the side of the building appearing perfectly flat to the camera regardless of the camera's current Y position.

How can I achieve this effect with the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the camera lookAt the target, but at the same y level as the camera.

Assuming self.target is a vector3 object and self.object is the camera:

If, for example, self.target is the camera's rotation center of the object, you wouldn't want to change the actual self.target vector. Make a copy of it first.

```
const newTarget = new THREE.Vector3( );

function render( ){

    // copy the target vector to newTarget so that the original self.target 
    // will not change and the camera can still rotate around the original
    // target.
    newTarget.copy( self.target );

    // Set newTarget's Y from the camera Y. So that is looks horizontal.
    newTarget.y = self.object.position.y; 

    // Make the camera look at the objects newTarget
    self.object.lookAt( newTarget);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well.  Would you mind updating your post to explain the need and the effect of calling the clone() operation and setting the Y value of the cloned object, instead of assigning to the target object's Y value directly?  Also, why doesn't changing the target's Y actually move the target itself and therefore put the camera back at the vertical center of it again?  I must admit I'm confused by that.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll add that.  Changing the target's Y should move the target...  I assumed that this is your own code, or are you referring to the TrackballControl's target? Because then, there might be some code in there that's interfering

Comment: I did change it from clone() to copy(). For the reason that if you do that on a larger scale; It will have to initialize a lot of new Vector3's. This way you only initialize the vector once and then set the components.

Comment: Thanks.  Is "nTarget" supposed to be "newTarget" in your revised code?